# Installing python script for ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, python

I am trying to use ffmpeg-normalize found here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ffmpeg-normalize

I am not familiar with python so I need some help to install the script.
 The documentation says to install with:

`pip install ffmpeg-normalize`

I am not sure what this means or how to implement it.

I have already added ffmpeg to `PATH` on a Windows 10 computer. I have ffmpeg in `c:\ffmpeg\bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python interpreter is able to run modules as scripts by specifying parameter '-m module-name'. PIP is a python module to install python libraries from maintained repository. Type

***python -m pip install ffmpeg-normalize***

preferably in admin command line and ffmpeg-normalize should automatically install (I suppose you have your python installation dir in PATH as well).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have PIP installed, then run the command from cmd

Answer (score 0):

First, you are going to want to search for your python scripts folder. If you are using Python 3.x, it is going to be found under you file directory using this path `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3x\Scripts`. I put x after Python3 if you have different versions, chose the newest one. If you are using Python 2.x, the file directory for the scripts folder will be `C:\Python2x\Scripts`. Once you have copied your file directory for the scripts folder, open command prompt by typing CMD into the search bar. Once there type `cd` then space and then paste your file directory to the scripts folder so it looks like `cd C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3x\Scripts` and hit enter. If there are no errors, then you can paste your pip install command `pip install ffmpeg-normalize` and hit enter and it should tell you that its been installed. By the way, this works for any pip install commands.